# i am updating all anaconda into latest version using > conda update - -all and this error is coming

Tags: python, anaconda

CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.

Comment: do you still get the same after running "conda clean --packages" ?

Comment: yes, same error is occuring

Comment: EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment.
  environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
this error is coming in updating the anaconda

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Make sure you have admin privileges. Try opening Anaconda prompt as Admin
2. try running `conda clean --packages` and then update.